# Executing a salesforce controller through javascript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code

I know it's easily possible to execute javascript through a controller, but is it possible to do it the other way around?

Use case scenario:

I have a list of products on the left side of a page. When I click one of these products, I have a CSS highlight appearing. I'd then like the javascript to rerender my search results function, "showtheresults".

It would allow users to drill down the product whose data they are searching through. The only way I can think of doing it is through javascript. Other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Is your product page built on salesforce or another technology?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Ajax toolkit. In JavaScript:

```
// Include Ajax toolkit
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js")} 

// Get selected Lead Ids
var leadIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};

// Call your class method
var result = sforce.apex.execute('CalledFromJavaScript', 'theMethod', {arg: leadIds});
```

Then in Apex:

```
// Make your class global and method a webservice:
global class CalledFromJavaScript 
{
   webService static Integer theMethod(List<Id> sObjectIds)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an output panel that you rendered selectively based on a boolean in your controller.  In this example set 'renderScriptPanel' when you'd like the showResults function to run.  If you're doing a partial page refresh make sure to refresh the id of the output panel.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="scriptPanel" rendered="{!renderScriptPanel}">
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    showTheResults();
  </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)